# what does \! mean? find . \! -user redis -exec chown redis '{}' +

Tags: docker, shell, find, sh

Regarding the redis docker image `ENTRYPOINT` script [`docker-entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/docker-library/redis/blob/master/6.0/docker-entrypoint.sh):

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

# first arg is `-f` or `--some-option`
# or first arg is `something.conf`
if [ "${1#-}" != "$1" ] || [ "${1%.conf}" != "$1" ]; then
        set -- redis-server "$@"
fi

# allow the container to be started with `--user`
if [ "$1" = 'redis-server' -a "$(id -u)" = '0' ]; then
        find . \! -user redis -exec chown redis '{}' +
        exec gosu redis "$0" "$@"
fi

exec "$@"
```

In the following line:

```
find . \! -user redis -exec chown redis '{}' +
```

what does `\!` mean?

Comment: `!` means `not`, so this command should find (and then `chown`) items that are **not** owned by the user "redis".  But a plain `!` has a special meaning to the shell (the command line processor), so the `!` must be written in a way that prevents that special treatment.  Placing a backslash immediately before the `!` does that.  That's why it is written as `\!` in that command.

Comment: Thank you very much to ottomeister.

Answer (score 0):

As per [GNU find documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Combining-Primaries-With-Operators), you can use both `! <expr>` or `-not <expr>` interchangeably to match items that do not match an expression:

**2.11 Combining Primaries With Operators**

> ! *expr*
> -not *expr*
>
> True if *expr* is false. In some shells, it is necessary to protect the ‘!’ from shell interpretation by quoting it.

The backslash (`\`) is used in several shells, for example Bourne-Again Shell (`bash`), to [escape reserved characters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Escape-Character.html) with special meanings that are not literally evaluated by the shell, which is the case of the [exclamation mark](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Reserved-Word-Index) (`!`) character.

In this case, as @ottomeister already referred in his comment, this command will apply a `chown redis <item>` to all items recursively found from the current directory whose owner is not already redis.